# Lossless compression of accelerometer signals

Tags: matlab, compression, signal-processing, accelerometer, sensors

I'm looking for the best method for compressing acceleration signals generated by mobile phones (Android) in MATLAB.  By "best" I mean in terms of volume reduction first and foremost, but also computational complexity as I will try and implement it on the phones at some point in the future. I am tending to wavelet compression: http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/wavelet/ref/mswcmp.html as it has been used for ECG signals which have similar characteristics.  I have also found some resources for sensors in general http://compsens.eecs.umich.edu/sensing_tutorial.php 
Any ideas StackOverflow?

Comment: Why not just use delta-encoding + deflate?

Comment: Wavelet compression is lossy. What are the statistical properties of the accelerometer signals? Delta encoding sounds ok, but remember that it is susceptible to error propagation if you have a noisy channel.

Comment: @EitanT thanks for the heads up, I hadn't checked that.

Comment: @JanDvorak from what I can see delta-encoding will be great at compressing an up-sampled signal back down to the original variable sampling rate (thanks android).  But, acceleration signals can be very dynamic, especially when the person is carrying their phone.  I can't see this providing a great compression ratio, or have I missed something?

Comment: @user1928047 if the acceleration signals can vary a lot, then you can't expect much compression. If your model is "can vary a lot but in nearly-linear fashion", apply the delta-encoding twice, then deflate. If you don't have a good model, you can't expect good compression.

Comment: I vote for double delta: (the torque on the phone => change in angular velocity => second derivation of acceleration due to gravity) shouldn't change much.

Comment: Statistical properties can vary greatly.  From very low variance (e.g. constant signal if the phone is on the table) to high variance and energy when the person carrying the phone.  The statistical properties are far more dependent on what is being done with the phone (and accelerometer) than the phone itself.  This is cool because you can then use inference over the accelerometer signals to identify what is being done with the phone.  But...it means that compression is most useful when the signal is dynamic (when something is being DONE with the phone).  Does that make sense?

Comment: @JanDvorak I don't think its possible to accurately acquire the angular velocity using an accelerometer, I think you need a gyroscope for that. Or am I mistaken?  I believe the 2 derivative of the acceleration is the change in "jerk," called the "jounce." Im not sure if that would be constant, or under what behavioral conditions it would change.  If it where to be constant than double-delta compression would be effective, did I understand that correctly?

Comment: @EmbeddAI I'm not trying to estimate the angular velocity. I'm just saying that it doesn't change much, and thus the second derivation of the acceleration due to gravity isn't very big (and the acceleration due to other vectors is localised in time - the user doesn't accelerate himself too often)

Comment: @JanDvorak ah ok I see what you mean now.  I'm not sure I agree with the statement that the angular velocity doesn't change much, e.g. riding a bicycle with the phone in your pants pocket, but its a valid point.  I'll give it a shot using this here: http://www.mathworks.de/matlabcentral/fileexchange/13197-differential-encodingdecoding

Thanks for your help everyone!

Comment: @EmbeddAI note that you can overcrank the number of deltas. Adding more than neccessary only has a slight impact, especially when DEFLATE is used (and not just HUFFMANN).

Comment: Basic question which has not been answered in this long comments thread: can you accept lossy compression?  If so, what are the frequency characteristics of the data that you care about or expect to make use of?

Comment: @MarkAdler the problem is that I am compressing the signal with no knowledge of which characteristics are of value and which are not. Any loss may dramatically affect characteristics which are important down the processing line but are not known at compression time, and evaluating that is a can of worms I would rather not open right now.

Answer (score 0):

There is an excellent overview in [this article](https://blog.timescale.com/blog/time-series-compression-algorithms-explained/). Simple-8b could be a good solution for your case, but I haven't found a Matlab implementation.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the characteristics of the data you are compressing. I will assume you want lossless encoding. The first step is to try and reduce the values to be encoded if possible; then use a variable length encoding to reduce the data transmitted.

There are a few ways of reducing the values to encode, and a few ways of implementing variable length encoding.

If the data does not change fast and has minimal noise, then 1 sample will be similar to the next and you can encode the value difference between samples. For example with data like:
x = [ 100, 103, 97, 99, 95, 96, 93];
the 1st-order difference becomes
xd = [3, -6, 2, -4, 1, -3];
you then encode these values plus the initial value of 100.
xd requires fewer bits to encode than the original x.

Some data is noisy and the best you can do is remove the DC offset from the data instead of a predictive filter like the differencer above.

If the noise or data is somewhat periodic and/or has a distinct frequency signature you could possibly use Linear predictive coding (LPC) which attempts to predict a future value so that you only have to encode a small number of LPC coefficients plus a small error signal. The error signal is the difference between the predicted values and the actual values. With the right data this can significantly reduce the values encoded and make variable length encoding more efficient. However, this approach only works for certain types of signals.

And finally to implement variable length encoding efficiently is going to depend on the histogram of the values being encoded. Ideally you would obtain representative data sets as reference, then calculate the probability of each value occurring and use the formula ideal_number_of_bits = -log2(p(x)) where x is a specific value to be encoded, and p(x) is the probability that a given value in the dataset is equal to x. The ideal_number_of_bits can be used as a guide for creating an optimal encoding scheme as you want to use the number of bits to encode a given value x. In practice ideal_number_of_bits is not an integer and you have to adjust the value from the ideal. There are many ways of deriving a scheme, I won't go into a list of them here.

A simple example of variable length encoding for 12-bit accelerometer data would be as follows:

if the value is between -120 (0b10001000) and 119 (0b01110111) inclusive, then encode the value in a single byte. If the value is outside this range then use 2 bytes:

negative numbers would be
| 1 0 0 0 0 b10 b9 b8 || b7-b0 |

positive numbers would be
| 0 1 1 1 1 b10 b9 b8 || b7-b0 |

Where the above shows the bits in 2 bytes and the value being encoded has bits b10-b0 plus a sign bit, and the number is a 2's complement number.

More elaborate schemes can be used involving greater variation in word-length. For example I have a dataset with optimal word-lengths ranging from 5 to 22 bits for 12-bit accelerometer data. but I can get 90% of the compression ratio using a byte aligned scheme ( roughly 50% compression vs 45% for the entropy limit/theoretical maximum compression). a byte aligned scheme will be much simpler to implement and faster to execute.

Your mileage, i.e. compression ratio, will vary depending on the histogram of your data.